# C++11 Check if at least one element in vector is not in another vector

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code in order to check if at least one element in vector is not in another vector.

**There are no duplicates in the vectors. Only unique elements**

Is there a more elegant way to do it by using the stl?

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool areVectorsDifferent(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b){
    if(a.size() != b.size()){
        return true;
    }
    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(),b.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size();i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
  return false;
}

int main() {
    bool isDifferent = false;
    vector<int> a = {1,2,3,5};
    vector<int> b = {4,3,2,1};
    std::cout << areVectorsDifferent(a,b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a return value if they are not different, and `return a != b;` is a bit nicer than your loop.

Comment: i corrected it. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this would work for something like `{1,2,3,5,5};` and `{1,1,2,3,5};` for example.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp there are no duplicated. Sorry I had to add it

Comment: yes Pete I corrected it

Comment: The two vectors are passed by `const` reference; they can't be modified, so the two calls to `sort` aren't valid.

Comment: @HaniGotc --  By sorting, you are changing the vectors being passed to you.  The function is, as the name suggests, only to determine if one vector is "different" than the other in some way, and not change the vectors elements.

Comment: Is this some online problem? If it is, then it is possible to drop `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "different", but:

```
bool areVectorsDifferent(const vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b){
    return a.size() != b.size()
        || std::set<int>{a.cbegin(), a.cend()} != std::set<int>{b.cbegin(), b.cend()};
}
```

Comment: sorry it should be IsAtLeastOneElementDifferent

Comment: So checking if the sizes are equal first should fix it, or do you have other constraints?

Comment: that's basically it

Comment: @HaniGotc "Basically" implies that you actually have other constraints. What are they?

Comment: No that's it @molbdnilo. But the provided answer is not compiling `error: missing template arguments before '{' token`

Comment: See my edit: you can elide the `<int>` in C++17, but not earlier.

Comment: [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/h1vn3hfzP).

Comment: @Botje I do not know who upvoted this answer but it is a wrong answer. For example the two different vectors { 1, 1, 2 } and { 1, 2, 2 } will be identical according to the approach.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Normally, yes. But [OP stated there were no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394783/c11-check-if-at-least-one-element-in-vector-is-not-in-another-vector/70394837?noredirect=1#comment124435926_70394783)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow OP said: *I wrote the following code in order to check if at least one element in vector is not in another vector* So this is what OP wants, I assume?

Comment: @justANewbie The question is unclear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry. Wasn't clear. there are no duplicates indeed

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solves your problem:

```cpp
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
auto are_different(const vector<T>& lhs, const vector<T>& rhs) -> bool {
    return lhs.size() != rhs.size() ||
           any_of(cbegin(lhs), cend(lhs), [&rhs](const auto& item) {
               return find(cbegin(rhs), cend(rhs), item) == cend(rhs);
           });
}
```

Comment: this is `O(n^2)` solution.

Comment: Now imagine if there were 100000 elements in each vector.  This will iterate 10000000000 times.